# Javascript: Assigning User Input as a Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, user-input

I'm just learning HTML, CSS, and Javascript and having a tough time grasping the JS. I've been working on this simple issue now for literally 6 hours. I've checked plenty of posts on SO, W3, re-read relevant chapters in Jon Duckett's book, and tried every combination I could think of in the code.

What I need to do is take a username from an input field  and run it through a function to change it in some way. I've seen other's posts with similar questions but haven't been able to create a solution yet. The issue that keeps happening is that when I place what should be the user input back to the page it uses the actual words `name.toUpperCase()` rather than the value I've given the variable `name`. I tried converting the name to uppercase in its own statement and then assigning that a variable, but that didn't work either. It seems like my js is never giving "name" a value to begin with.

JS:

```
var name = document.getElementById('nameEntry');
var compliment = document.getElementById('compliment');
var input = document.getElementById('submitjs');

input.onclick = transformName;

function transformName () {
    var elcompliment = document.getElementById('compliment');
    elcompliment.textContent = 'name.toUpperCase( )' + ' YOU ROCK!';
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jsform">
    <h2> Enter your name and see it change!</h2>
    <input type="text" name="nameEntry" id="nameEntry" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitjs" value="submit" id="submitjs"/>

   <div>
    <p id="compliment">Great Job!</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Tip of the day: don't use `name` for variable names

Comment: You just as singing input went to variable name not it's value , to do so use.   var name = document.getElementById('nameEntry');.value;

Answer (score 1):

Since you are retrieving input value using element's id, there is no need for form.

```js
function transformName () {
  var name = document.getElementById('nameEntry').value;
  var compliment = document.getElementById('compliment');

    compliment.innerHTML  = name.toUpperCase( ) + ' YOU ROCK!';
};
```

```html
<div class="jsform">
    <h2> Enter your name and see it change!</h2>
    <input type="text" name="nameEntry" id="nameEntry" />
    <input type="button" onclick="transformName()" value="Transform me"/>

   <div>
    <p id="compliment">Great Job!</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: dude I appreciate it this so much. Obviously that works, what I don't understand is where I was using a form?

Comment: Since you're using submit button instead of a regular button, and there is a class called jsform, I assumed there was a form wrapping jsform.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` variable currently refers to DOM element. The `value` property returns the data entered in the `input` element.

> The value property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a text field.

```js
var name = document.getElementById('nameEntry').value;
var compliment = document.getElementById('compliment');
var input = document.getElementById('submitjs');

input.onclick = transformName;

function transformName () {
    var name = document.getElementById('nameEntry').value;
    var elcompliment = document.getElementById('compliment');
    elcompliment.innerHTML = name.toUpperCase()+' YOU ROCK!';
};
```

```html
<div class="jsform">
  <h2> Enter your name and see it change!</h2>
  <input type="text" name="nameEntry" id="nameEntry" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitjs" value="submit" id="submitjs" />

  <div>
    <p id="compliment">Great Job!</p>
  </div>

</div>
```